# How to get all SharePoint Web Applications in the Central Administration Page from code behind

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, central-administration, web-application

How can I have the list of all existing SharePoint Web Applications and their site collections from code behind .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in SPWebService.ContentService.WebApplications)
{
    string webUrl = webApp.GetResponseUri(SPUrlZone.Default).AbsoluteUri;
    SPSiteCollection sites = webApp.Sites;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SPWebApplicationCollection webAppColl = SPWebService.ContentService.WebApplications;

if (webAppColl != null)
 { 
   foreach (SPWebApplication spWebApp in webAppColl)
   {
        SPSiteCollection sites = spWebApp.Sites;
   }
}
```